# Ruby on Rails: putting class with submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering why we have to add a `nil` when putting `:class => "class_name"`

```
<%= submit_tag nil, :class => "class_name" %>
```

but for this:

```
<%= f.submit class: "class-Name" %>
```

I don't need to add the `nil`

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

```
     <%= submit_tag("Update", :id=>"button", :class=>"Test", :name=>"submit") %>
```

First parameter is required and it would be value and they any parameter you want to specify, can be done in a hash like :key=>"value".

Answer (score 9):

A look to the [way that submit_tag method was implemented](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4179470f0116a08a1838c474ba5541bb33658c9d/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L417) clearly answers your question.

```
  def submit_tag(value = "Save changes", options = {})
    options = options.stringify_keys

    if disable_with = options.delete("disable_with")
      options["data-disable-with"] = disable_with
    end

    if confirm = options.delete("confirm")
      options["data-confirm"] = confirm
    end

    tag :input, { "type" => "submit", "name" => "commit", "value" => value }.update(options)
  end
```

It takes two arguments, the first is `value` which by default is "Save changes" and the second is a Hash of options. If you don't pass `nil` then it will assume that that's the value you want for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are two different methods...

The "submit" method doesn't take a caption because it can infer one from the form that the method is called on, and what object was used to build the form.

The "submit_tag" method is not called on a form object.  It is used for more customized form building (more separated from your activerecord model, for example) and so the code can't infer a caption and must get a value as the first argument.  All the "formelement_tag" methods (documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html), for example) are like this and can infer less based on your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer is that `submit_tag` and `submit` are simply different form helper methods that takes different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The _tag series of methods usually require a name parameter (otherwise they'd be fairly useless tags, so it's always the first argument instead of part of the hash. Because the submit helper is called as part of the form, Rails can assume the field's name property and can then make the options hash the first argument.